# how to put name difference for daily backup

Tags: sql, oracle, expdp

I created a backup cmd file with this code

```
EXPDP system/system EXCLUDE=statistics DIRECTORY=bkp_dir DUMPFILE=FULLDB.DMP LOGFILE=FULLDB.log FULL=Y
```

it works good, but, when I run the backup again, it finds that the file exists
and terminate the process. it will not run unless I delete the previous file or rename it. I want to add something to the dumpfile and logfile name that creates a daily difference between them, something like the system date, or a copy number or what else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option [**`REUSE_DUMPFILES`**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-65DCC12E-E370-46E0-86C0-4EDFDD78DF25.htm#SUTIL862) specifies whether to overwrite a preexisting dump file.

> Normally, Data Pump Export will return an error if you specify a dump
>   file name that already exists. The REUSE_DUMPFILES parameter allows
>   you to override that behavior and reuse a dump file name.

If you wish to dump separate file names for each day, you may use a variable using `date` command in  Unix/Linux environment.

```
DUMPFILE=FULLDB_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').DMP
```

Similar techniques are available in Windows, which you may explore if you're running `expdp` in Windows environment.

Comment: thank you Kaushik, I have solved it with date command
in windows it will be like this:
DUMPFILE=FULLDB-%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%.DMP